Overflown Content Clipping when align-items set to center of flex child
I have this bit of code. A salmon coloured part is a child with a flex container that has overflow set to auto and it also set to fill the remaining space vertically.


 <div
      style="
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      "
    >
      <div>THIS IS THE HEADER TEXT</div>

      <div style="flex-grow: 1; background: salmon; overflow-y: auto">
        <div
          style="
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
          "
        >
          <div>
            <div>Sub header</div>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



If the text within it does not overflow all is good. However, as soon as it overflows, the top part Sub header get cut.


 <div
      style="
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      "
    >
      <div>THIS IS THE HEADER TEXT</div>

      <div style="flex-grow: 1; background: salmon; overflow-y: auto">
        <div
          style="
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
          "
        >
          <div>
            <div>Sub header</div>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



Removing align-items: center; seems to fix this issue


<div
      style="
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      "
    >
      <div>THIS IS THE HEADER TEXT</div>

      <div style="flex-grow: 1; background: salmon; overflow-y: auto">
        <div
          style="
            display: flex;

            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
          "
        >
          <div>
            <div>Sub header</div>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              voluptatem, ducimus magnam vero asperiores culpa rerum laudantium
              officia ad modi inventore dicta reiciendis, minus sit incidunt
              praesentium numquam voluptatibus quae.
            </p>

            <p>bla bla</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



Is there anyway to fix it without removing align-items: center;?
